# Making bootstrap nav-tabs active using AngularJS Filtering

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

so I have a webpage with a table that gets updated according to filters on some nav-tabs I have.

I cannot make these tabs active, ie. you don't know which tab you're on and what you have filtered on. I assume this is because the only thing my tab does is filter angular;

```
          <li role="presentation"><a data-ng-click="areaFilter = 'Odder'">Odder</a></li>
```

And nothing more. How do I work around this ? I have found solutions when there is a webpage redirect, but I dont do that here, I only update a table.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who might have this problem sometime in the future, I simply made this Jquery script to handle the nav-tabs or pills;

```
$(".nav-tabs li").on("click", function() {$(".nav-tabs li").removeClass("active");$(this).addClass("active");});
```